# Automate HAR file generation from Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, automation, spdy, har

Basically what I need is a way to automate the *result* of the following operations:

1. Open a new tab
2. Open the Network tab in the developer tools
3. Load a URL
4. Select "Save All as HAR"

Often, proposed solutions involve the use of [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), [browsermob-proxy](http://opensource.webmetrics.com/browsermob-proxy/), or [pcap2har](https://github.com/andrewf/pcap2har). Those won't fit my case since I need to work with [SPDY](http://dev.chromium.org/spdy) traffic.

I tried to dive into the [Google Chrome Extensions API](http://developer.chrome.com/stable/extensions/api_index.html) and indeed I managed to automate some tasks, but still no luck for HAR file generation. [This method](http://developer.chrome.com/stable/extensions/devtools.network.html#method-getHAR) is particularly promising, but I still can't figure out how would I use it.

In other words, I need something like [this experiment](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/spdy-for-mobile) from *the Google guys*. Note the following:

> We used Chrome's [remote debugging interface](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging) with a custom client that starts up the browser on the phone, clears its cache and other state, initiates a web page load, and receives the Chrome developer tools messages to determine the page load times and other performance metrics.

Any ideas?

---

## Solution

For the curious, I ended up with a Node.js module that automates such tests: [chrome-har-capturer](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-har-capturer). This also gave me the opportunity to dig deeper into the [Remote Debugging Protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/index) and to write a lower-level Node.js interface for general-purpose Chrome automation: [chrome-remote-interface](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface).

Comment: How to use the chrome-har-capturer ? Could you please guide ?

Comment: Isn't the README enough? If you have any doubt feel free to file an issue.

Comment: Nope README misses examples, even some options aren't described.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The short answer is, there is no way to get at the data you are after directly. The `getHAR` method is only applicable to extensions meant to extend DevTools itself. The good news is, you can construct the HAR file yourself without too much trouble - this is exactly [what phantom.js does](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/netsniff.js).

1. Start Chrome with remote debugging
2. Connect to Chrome on the debugging port with a websocket connection
3. Enable "Network" debugging, you can also clear cache, etc - see [Network API](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/1.0/network).
4. Tell the browser to navigate to the page you want to capture, and Chrome will stream all the request meta-data back to you.
5. Massage the network data into HAR format, ala phantom.js
6. ...
7. Profit.

For a head start, I have a post that with sample Ruby code that should you get started with steps 1-4: http://www.igvita.com/2012/04/09/driving-google-chrome-via-websocket-api/

Comment: Quite funny that a _real Google guy_ answered my question! :) In these days I got a glimpse of the topics you mentioned, and finally you provided me the glue. Let me try it out, I'll be back soon with some feedback...

Comment: Ok, this is definitely the way to go. Now I have a nodejs script that launch Chrome, start tcpdump, open a WebSocket, do some setup, load an URL and finally dump the HAR file... I followed the example of PhantomJS you provided, the HAR spec and the Network API, but there's still something about the timings that I don't get, in particular: how can I fill `timings.receive` field? From what I've understood: a request starts at `requestTime`; waiting from server starts at `requestTime +  sendEnd` and ends at `Network.responseReceived` (`timestamp`), is this correct?

Comment: Or maybe the whole response is received at `Network.responseReceived` (`timestamp`)?

Comment: responseReceived should contain all the timing data within (as part of NavTiming). You definitely don't want to be in the business of calculating these times yourself.

Comment: I hope so, but all I have is this [ResourceTiming](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/1.0/network#type-ResourceTiming) object and I can't figure out how to determine when a response is fully received, there's no field like `responseEnd`.

Comment: It looks like you might want to also listen for the Network.loadingFinished event. If you filter for Network.responseReceived, then you will get the notification when the header is available, and you can save the request ID + other meta-data about it, and then correlate it with loadingFinished to get final timestamp.

Comment: Great, everything should be fine now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear. If you have your code up anywhere, would love to take a look!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. I also using "chrome-har-capturer" for this. But I have one question - is it possible to make the same on some server (not desktop computer), where I have only some console access. 
I mean is Chrome depends on really showing browser on desktop, or it could work in console too? Hope you understand me :)

Comment: For those that just read comments, @cYrus put the code he came up with [on github as chrome-har-capturer](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-har-capturer), which he mentions at the bottom of his question now

Answer (score 2):

By now there's a browser plugin to do that: https://github.com/devtools-html/har-export-trigger

It uses the WebExtensions DevTools API and I got it to work with both Firefox and Chrome.

See my code for Chrome here: https://github.com/theri/web-measurement-tools/blob/master/load/load_url_using_chrome.py#L175

Automatically installing the plugin in Chrome is a bit more complicated than in Firefox, but feasible - I extracted the plugin archive locally and then link to it in chrome_prefs.json (see same repository).

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it helps, [HAR Recorder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/har-recorder/emfabjnfjiknifjlfpjobbecfepplhkd/) uses chrome debug protocol to record HAR and generate a har file **(without opening devtools)**. If you want a variation, you can fork and make changes on it.

Comment: Be careful while using HAR Recorder. Review its privacy practices which say: `Privacy practices

HAR Recorder has disclosed the following information regarding the collection and usage of your data. More detailed information can be found in the developer's privacy policy.

HAR Recorder collects the following:

User activity
For example: network monitoring, clicks, mouse position, scroll or keystroke logging`