# Chrome Remote Debugging Protocol messages => Logstash for visualisation

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, logstash, kibana

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35518142/954442), has anybody tried integrating [Chrome RDP messages](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/tot) with Logstash (as an input), for subsequent piping into Elasticsearch / Kibana etc, so that network timings and performance metrics can be visualised?

Having looked at the [available Logstash input plugins](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/input-plugins.html), nothing seems a direct fit, but can any of the existing ones be retrofitted to support this? I can't tell if this protocol is available over HTTP.

I plan to initiate the process [using ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging/performance-log). Language, versions aren't important at this stage.