# Can I programatically get Chrome Devtools Performance information?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I like the chrome devtools performance tab information, but I want to be able to record the performance profile during an automated functional test.  I can execute javascript to get initial load performance data (`window.performance`), and what I'm looking for is something that like to get Performance profile information.  Simple things like the duration of a network calls and profile summary.

Something like:

```
events =[
  { type: Network request,
    URL: someURL,
    Duration: 431.43 ms,
    Request Method: POST,
    Priority: High,
    Mime Type: application/json,
    Encoded Data: 544 B,
    Decoded Body: 50 B,
    Initiator: JavascriptInsert.js:49
  },
  {
    type: Network request,
    URL: someOtherURL,
    Duration: 81.50 ms,
    Request Method: POST,
    Priority: High,
    Mime Type: text/plain,
    Encoded Data: 260 B,
    Initiator: angular.js:10514  
  }
]
```

and

```
summary= {
  Loading: 2.5ms,
  Scripting: 587.6ms,
  Rendering: 77.6ms,
  Painting: 52.5ms,
  Other: 109.3ms,
  Idle: 3040.1ms
}
```

Comment: These look like good starting points: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools and https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/integrating

Comment: Sure, [`window.performance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming) is your friend.

Comment: @Bergi window.performance tells you the "inital" load of the page.  For an Angular / SPA, it doesn't give you any details about any of the Angular service calls.

Comment: @MattWestlake [`performance.getEntriesByType("resource")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/getEntriesByType) should get you the details you're looking for. I'm not talking about `performance.navigation` or `performance.timing`

Comment: @Bergi that wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it's a good start.  Now If you know of anyway I can get the breakdown of painting vs downloading etc. that would be everything I need.

Comment: @Bergi if you want to post your solution as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The durations of network calls and similar details are available in the [`window.performance` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming) as well. You can use [`performance.getEntriesByType("resource")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/getEntriesByType) to get the entries for all requests that your page made.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Selenium, use `browser.get_log` to obtain all performance logs. My solution uses Python, but it should be similar for any supported language.

First, set up headless Chrome:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.set_headless(True)

# for possible entries refer to current implementation at
# https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/test/chromedriver/capabilities.cc#372
perfLogPrefs = {
    "traceCategories": "toplevel,disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline.frame,blink.console,disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline,benchmark"
}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("perfLoggingPrefs", perfLogPrefs)

desired_capabilities = chrome_options.to_capabilities()
desired_capabilities['loggingPrefs'] = {
    "browser": "ALL",  # use this for console.log output, and obtain later
    "performance": "ALL",
}

browser = webdriver.Chrome(
    chrome_options=chrome_options,
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
```

After the tests are finished, obtain logs using `get_log` and extract the entries:

```
# based more or less on
# https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging/performance-log#TOC-Collecting-Log-Entries
import json
with open(base_filename + '.perf.log', 'w') as f:
    logs = browser.get_log('performance')
    f.write('[')
    add_comma = False
    for entry in logs:
        if add_comma:
            f.write(',\n')
        message = json.loads(entry['message'])['message']
        json.dump(message['params'], f)
        add_comma = True
    f.write(']')
```

The entries are similar to ones described in [Trace Event Format documentation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CvAClvFfyA5R-PhYUmn5OOQtYMH4h6I0nSsKchNAySU/edit#). However, I can't figure out the proper file format to load it later in Chrome DevTools Performance tab. I get an error:

```
Malformed timeline data: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

If someone manages to load that in Chrome, please update my answer (or post answer in [How to visualize log of chrome DevTool protocol messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35518142/1762343)).